# FloatingActionButton rotate on clicking button itself

Tags: android, android-animation, floating-action-button

I am using `FloatingActionButton` and `OnClick`. I wanted to display `PopupMenu` and rotate the same FAB button with nice Animation (rotating 90 degree).

[image]

On click, it should animate itself :

[image]

I am able to display a `PopupMenu` on its `OnClick` method but i am not able to rotate FAB **itself**. In fact, I am able to animate all other `FloatingActionButton` around it but i tried non of the `FloatingActionButton` can animate itself `OnClick` method.

I also tried NOT using `FloatingActionButton`, but a Simple Button that can animate (rotate) itself..

```
public class FloatingButtonPanel extends Fragment {

    //.... Other code... 
    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                             Bundle savedInstanceState) {


        //.... Other code... 
        final FloatingActionButton butA = (FloatingActionButton) view.findViewById(R.id.fb_menu);

        butA.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                rotateAnimation(v);
            }
        });

        return view;
    }
    public static void rotateAnimation(View v){
        // Create an animation instance
        final Animation an = new RotateAnimation(0, 90, v.getWidth()/2, v.getHeight()/2);
        an.setDuration(1000);
        an.setFillAfter(true);
        v.clearAnimation();
        v.startAnimation(an);
    }
}
```

Can anyone help ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First thing is never try to show Over flow menu in the FloatingActionButton(FAB) options menu as per [Google](https://www.google.co.in/design/spec/components/buttons-floating-action-button.html#buttons-floating-action-button-transitions) design.

Second Thing Fab is just an image view. So like the other image vies you can rotatate it using Matrix

```
    Matrix matrix = new Matrix();
    FloatingActionButton fab=new FloatingActionButton(this);
    fab.setScaleType(ImageView.ScaleType.MATRIX);   //required
    matrix.postRotate((float) angle, pivX, pivY);
    fab.setImageMatrix(matrix);
```

You can proceed further with [Animators](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/graphics/prop-animation.html) to hide and show the options menu.

Comment: Thank you very much for your reply and useful information, i will implement using that way. I appreciate your help.

@Karthik
Other question I have if.. I have to implement above design for my application what type of controls i should use, how can i implement it (Button which looks like FABs and it need to have menu ). What is the best approach to design this UI (as per requirement)

Comment: you can use latest support design [library](http://android-developers.blogspot.in/2015/05/android-design-support-library.html) . Also follow these [principles](https://www.google.co.in/design/spec/components/buttons-floating-action-button.html#buttons-floating-action-button-floating-action-button)

Comment: I don't know why but this is not working for me. My fab is in the xml. Is there any trick I am missing?

Answer (score 0):

Thank you very much @Karthik.

With the useful info you game in your answer, I found another way to work around this, and create same floating menu buttons using help of [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9884202/custom-circle-button).

By using this custom-circle-button I could use animation + floating menu.

[image]