# Android : Difference FloatingActionButton and normal button

Tags: android, floating-action-button

I have tried demo [FloatingActionButton](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/design/widget/FloatingActionButton.html). I don't see real differences why I should change from normal button class to `FloatingActionButton` because if I want to make round button, I can try this tutorial:[make circular button](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9884202/custom-circle-button)

As definition of Android Document:

> Floating action buttons are used for a special type of promoted
>   action. They are distinguished by a circled icon floating above the UI
>   and have special motion behaviors related to morphing, launching, and
>   the transferring anchor point.
>
> Floating action buttons come in two sizes: the default and the mini.
>   The size can be controlled with the fabSize attribute.

I think everything here I can implement easily in normal button such as size, circle, above UI. Just one thing I don't understand:

> special motion behaviors related to morphing, launching, and the
>   transferring anchor point

I don't really know this. What does it mean about `morphing lauching and transfering anchor point`. Please explain for me.

thanks :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is a nice article about Floating Action Buttons at Google's Material Design Guidelines: https://www.google.com/design/spec/components/buttons-floating-action-button.html There is a lot of examples about how you can (and should and shouldn't) use the Floating Action Button at activity transitions and how it can be used to create nice, meaningful and logical animations.

If you use the correct Floating Action Button (the one from the Support Design library) together with CoordinatorLayout, it will also take care of Snackbars. When a Snackbar appears, the Floating Action Button will move up in order not to be covered by the Snackbar. You can check it out here: http://android-developers.blogspot.cz/2015/05/android-design-support-library.html