# Custom circle shaped toggle button with animation

Tags: android, android-layout, button, android-animation, togglebutton

I want to create custom Toggle button with animation and I need it to be circle. How can I create toggle circle button with animation?

Also I do not know how to make custom button!

Do you have any suggestion?

Comment: This has been answered already, [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9884202/custom-circle-button)!

Comment: Yes there is answer for custom button with animation and also there is custom 
 circle button but there is no custom toggle button with animation and need to be circle. If there is please share the link

Comment: Add desired output how it looks like your toggle button?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Add this in your `build.gradle`

```
dependencies {
    compile 'me.rishabhkhanna:CustomToggle:1.0.0'
}
```

and use this instead of `ToggleButton`

```
<me.rishabhkhanna.customtogglebutton.CustomToggleButton
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_gravity="center"
    android:textOn="toggle button"
    android:textOff="toggle button"
    ></me.rishabhkhanna.customtogglebutton.CustomToggleButton>
```

here's the [link](https://github.com/Rishabhk07/Custom-Toggle-Button) of the website