# How to change button background when you click on the listview item

Tags: android, listview, layout, button, inflate

I have a listview and I have inflate it with a custom layout containing 1 ImageView, 2 TextView and 1 Button. I want to change the button background when I click  on a listview item , but I don't be able to perform it. Can someone help me, please? Thank you so much in advance.

[image]

row_segnalibro.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
     android:id="@+id/LinearLayout01"
     android:orientation="horizontal"
     android:layout_width="match_parent" android:layout_height="50dp" >

<ImageView android:id="@+id/ImageView01" android:src="@drawable/star" 
android:layout_height="40dp"
    android:layout_width="40dp"
    android:enabled="false"
    android:focusable="false"
    android:focusableInTouchMode="false"
    android:clickable="false"
    android:paddingLeft="10dp"  />

<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@+id/LinearLayout02"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:layout_width="220dp" android:layout_height="match_parent">

<TextView 
    android:id="@+id/tvRow1"
    android:layout_width="220dp"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"   
    android:focusable="false"
    android:focusableInTouchMode="false"
    android:clickable="false"
    android:paddingLeft="10dp"    
    android:paddingTop="5dp"
    android:textColor="#0967AD"
    android:textStyle="bold"
    />
<TextView 
    android:id="@+id/tvRow2"
    android:layout_below="@id/tvRow1"
    android:layout_width="220dp"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"   
    android:focusable="false"
    android:focusableInTouchMode="false"
    android:clickable="false"
    android:paddingLeft="10dp"    
    android:textColor="#0967AD"
    android:textStyle="bold"
 />
</RelativeLayout>
<Button 
    android:id="@+id/butt_segnalib"
    android:background="@drawable/freccia_o"
    android:focusable="false"
    android:focusableInTouchMode="false"
    android:layout_width="20dp"
    android:layout_height="20dp"
    android:layout_gravity="center" />
```

Segnalibro.java

```
  public class Segnalibro extends ListActivity{
            super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.segnalibro);

         lv = (ListView) getListView();         
 .....some code
      MySimpleCursorAdap myadap = new MySimpleCursorAdap(getApplicationContext(),R.layout.rowlayout_segnalibro,curr,campi, to);
         lv.setAdapter(myadap);
         lv.setClickable(true); 

          lv.setOnItemClickListener( new  OnItemClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View v,int position, long arg3) {
                    Log.i("","I have clicked on item "+position);   

            }        
        });
```

MySimpleCursorAdap.java

```
      public class MySimpleCursorAdap extends SimpleCursorAdapter{

        public MySimpleCursorAdap(Context context, int layout, Cursor c, String[] from, int[] to) {
            super(context, layout, c, from, to);
        this.mLayout = layout;
        this.curr = c;
                 this.cont = context;
          }

 public void bindView(View view, Context context, final Cursor cursor) {

   ....some code

 /*       Button butt = (Button) view.findViewById(R.id.butt_segnalib); 
          butt.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
     .....code to change the background
     }
        }); */
  }
```

in MySimpleCursorAdap I can get the Button with the method findViewById, how I can to do it in the class Segnalibro?

Comment: is **freccia_o** is a state list..?

Comment: freccia_o is a png image

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ok.. so basically you need a state list for acheiving it.. see [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1521640/standard-android-button-with-a-different-color) to know how to create it.. and then set it as background of your button..

Comment: thank you very much, I have used the signpainter's solution. Probably I will try also your solution to curiosity :)

Comment: @crazykeyboard .. may be it works.. using statelist is preferred since you don't have keep changing button image at runtime everytime its clicked...

Comment: I have done it , it works perfectly. I have used a statelist (now I know what this is) and I have used the method onListItemClick(...) with the code 

Button butt = (Button) v.findViewById(R.id.butt_segnalib);
                      if(butt.isEnabled())
       butt.setEnabled(false); 
      else 
       butt.setEnabled(true);

It's a fantastic thing,thank you very much :)

Answer (score 1):

When you use `ListActivity` as base class you don't have to create a `onItemClickListener` yourself, it's already there. Just override `protected void onListItemClick(ListView l, View v, int position, long id)`. Inside you will be able to fetch the Button via it's id.

http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/ListActivity.html

```
protected void onListItemClick(ListView l, View v, int position, long id)
{
    Button bt = (Button) v.findViewById(R.id.button);

    //do something fancy with the button
}
```

Comment: Thank you very much it works, you have made my day very happy. Have a wonderful day :)

Comment: @crazykeyboard If you just want to change the button's background as it's state changes (pressed, focused, etc.) I would use sandy's solution. That way you have all in one place and can easily re-use the effect on the button in other activities.

Answer (score 1):

Try to add a ClickListener for the list item view in the bindView method:

```
public void bindView(View view, Context context, final Cursor cursor) {

   //some code

   view.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {  
    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {
        final ImageButton button = (ImageButton)v.findViewById(R.id.list_item_button);
        button.setBackgroundColor(...)
        }
   });
)
```