# Changing ImageButton's background color according to state

Tags: android, imagebutton

I saw this question (http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1521640/standard-android-button-with-a-different-color) and that works fine for normal buttons. Now I wanted to apply the same procedere on my ImageButtons, on which I add an Icon with android:src="@drawable/icon_name"

I defined following style in styles.xml

```
<style name="ImageButton" parent="android:Widget.ImageButton">
        <item name="android:background">@drawable/custom_image_button</item>
</style>
```

and set up the custom_image_button.xml in analogy with the custom_button.xml from my quote, but the problem is, by defining my Theme, I can find a `android:buttonStyle`, but no `android:imageButtonStyle` or something similiar. Is there another way to get to that point? Or is the only option to create a single icon for every state when customizing ImageButtons?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you need to double-check -- there is an `android:imageButtonStyle` attribute for themes. See [themes.xml](https://github.com/android/platform_frameworks_base/blob/master/core/res/res/values/themes.xml) for all of the possible attributes for a theme.

Comment: that's weird. I mean, with ctrl+space there are all possibilities shown, there was no imageButtonStyle. But it works, so I think I should try once more before posting a question ;-) thanks!