# Android margin not working as expected

Tags: android, android-layout

Consider the following code and output:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent" >

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/button1"
        android:layout_width="100dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_margin="0dp"
        android:text="A" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/button2"
        android:layout_width="100dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_margin="0dp"
        android:text="B" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/button3"
        android:layout_width="100dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_margin="0dp"
        android:text="C" />

</LinearLayout>
```

[image]

Because `android:layout_margin="0dp"`, the buttons should touch each other, but this is not happening. Please explain this behavior. What can I do to eliminate the gap between the buttons?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That is due the style applied to the button.
You can avoid that by setting `android:background` but you will loose the click effect and all .

Comment: is it possible to extend the default button style and override only the margin property?

Comment: yes. you can change that. refer [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1521640/standard-android-button-with-a-different-color)