# Custom Holo Button

Tags: android, button

I've tried searching and using custom [selectors](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1521640/standard-android-button-with-a-different-color) other people have posted here, using the set colour filter and various other things. I think I'm getting it completely wrong because in complete honesty I'm not great with designing having just started developing, but I still don't imagine it can be as complex to do what I want as I have seen:

I've developed an app for froyo and up. I want the background colour of the button to be the holo green and holo orange as on the swatches on the [Android developer website](http://developer.android.com/design/style/color.html). That's all I want to be different. I want the standard blue highlight when pressing the button on holo or the standard button onpress etc. behaviour expected in froyo, gingerbread etc.

I would really appreciate any guidance on this. Thank you guys in advance!

Answer (score 7, accepted):

**EDIT :**

There is a much easier way to change the colors of the holo theme. This website will do it for you :

http://android-holo-colors.com

---

The only way to customize the holo buttons is to edit the button drawables with an image editor like Photoshop. Here is how :

- Open the `platforms/android-17/data/res` folder in your SDK directory and find the holo buttons in the drawable folders (they start with `btn_default_holo_...`).
- Open them with your image editor and simply change their colors (hue/saturation) to match the color you want. There are 3 or 4 different drawables, one per button state.
- Save them in the corresponding drawable folder of your app. You have to do this for each screen density you want to handle (`mdpi`, `hdpi`, `xhdpi` are usually enough).

I haven't tested, but it may be enough to just edit the `xhdpi` buttons. They will be scaled down to the lower densities.

Once you customized each drawable, you have to create a selector that you will use as your custom button. Here is an example of a selector I use in one of my apps to create a green holo button :

```
<selector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <item android:state_window_focused="false" android:state_enabled="true"
          android:drawable="@drawable/__btn_green_normal_holo_light"/>
    <item android:state_window_focused="false" android:state_enabled="false"
          android:drawable="@drawable/__btn_default_disabled_holo_light"/>
    <item android:state_pressed="true"
          android:drawable="@drawable/__btn_default_pressed_holo_light"/>
    <item android:state_focused="true" android:state_enabled="true"
          android:drawable="@drawable/__btn_default_focused_holo_light"/>
    <item android:state_enabled="true"
          android:drawable="@drawable/__btn_green_normal_holo_light"/>
    <item android:state_focused="true"
          android:drawable="@drawable/__btn_default_disabled_focused_holo_light"/>
    <item
          android:drawable="@drawable/__btn_default_disabled_holo_light"/>
</selector>
```

Here is an example of a modified [green holo button drawable](https://github.com/Daimas/elygo-lib/blob/master/elygo-lib/res/drawable-xhdpi/__btn_green_normal_holo_light.9.png). You can check the other drawables of my project if you are interested, I do exactly what you want to do (I also have a red button).

Comment: Thank you for your answer! My only worry is for this I would have to adapt it for each Android version so as to mimic the usual (orange in gingerbread and blue in ics etc.), or have I got this wrong?

Comment: You're right, but you can also use holo buttons for all versions. That's what I do, and what several well known apps do. They are better than the old 2.1 buttons.

Comment: Okay, I'll do that! :) Thank you a lot!

Comment: Worked amazingly! Though I used the paint tool rather than hue and saturation. Now I've just got to work out how to unflatten the buttons.

Comment: The links both look dead