# How to set android button background color (normal + pressed) from android xml

Tags: android

I do not have images but 3 rgb patterns which I need to apply on button normal button press etc.
Morevoer the text color should change accordingly.

How to use the 6 rgb (3+3) and apply to Button either in xml or from code.
PS: I am not looking for a selector image based solution, where I have to create images when I plan to change color

Comment: why -2 ? someone please care to write why -2

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Take a look at this [thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1521640/standard-android-button-with-a-different-color), it explains it all, even how to use only one image with different effects. From it:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>    
<selector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <item android:state_pressed="true" android:drawable="@drawable/rbutton_pressed" />
    <item android:state_focused="true" android:drawable="@drawable/button_focus" />
    <item android:drawable="@drawable/button_rest" />
</selector>
```

This is the method with three different drawables. With the following code you can appli some effects, as stated in the thread:

```
button.getBackground().setColorFilter(0xFF00FF00, PorterDuff.Mode.MULTIPLY);
```

or

```
button.getBackground().setColorFilter(new LightingColorFilter(0xFFFFFFFF, 0xFFAA0000));
```