# Is it possible to specify border in android button?

Tags: android, button

Is it possible to specify border in Android button in the main.xml? 
[p.s. 
without the 'separate xml file containing stroke tag' but in the original file where I define the button and also 
without the 'dynamically by programming' solution
and 'images' solution]

```
  <Button
    android:background="#FFFFFF"
    android:layout_width="0dp"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:text="Player 3"
    android:layout_x="0px"
    android:layout_y="0px"
    android:id="@+id/p3"
    android:layout_weight="1" 

/>
```

here I am changing the background dynamically but the problem is, for 2 buttons there is no border.

Comment: You could use shape-selector xml to make custom button with border of your own choice for different buttons states, Have a look at [Standard Android Button with a different color](http://stackoverflow.com/q/1521640/593709)

Comment: layout xmls are for layout, not for graphical specifics

Comment: @AdilSoomro ,i was kindof hoping that there would be sumthing i had missed .thnk u for the answer. i might have to go with the shape selector approach.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

**This is not the recommended way to do it because it causes [overdraw](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=T52v50r-JfE) and adds unnecessary views, [Gunaseelan has the proper method](https://stackoverflow.com/a/17565316/494879).**

---

There's no concept of borders as an attribute. The accepted way is to use a separate drawable as the background to the `View` (using `stroke` as you've mentioned and as @gunaseelan writes).

The other (not recommended) way is to enclose your `Button` in another `View` like a `LinearLayout`, set the background color to the desired border colour on the encapsulating `View` and padding on the outer `View` too.

```
<LinearLayout
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:background="#342334"
    android:padding="5dp"
    >
    <Button
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:text="whatwhaaat"
        />
</LinearLayout>
```

The value of the padding will indicate the thickness of the border. This method is not recommended as you end up with an extra `View` in your layout, and another layer of overdraw (it draws the `LinearLayout` then the `Button` on top).

Comment: well,i was kindof hoping that there would be sumthing i had missed.thnk u for the answer

Answer (score 35):

Try to use shape

my_shape.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<shape xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:shape="rectangle" >

    <corners
        android:bottomLeftRadius="7dp"
        android:bottomRightRadius="7dp"
        android:radius="0.1dp"
        android:topLeftRadius="7dp"
        android:topRightRadius="7dp" />

    <solid android:color="#FFFFFF" />

    <stroke
        android:width="1dp"
        android:color="#E8E6E7" />

</shape>
```

And Button

```
<Button
    android:id="@+id/button1"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:background="@drawable/my_shape"
    android:text="Button" />
```

Screenshot

[image]

I hope this will help you.

Comment: hi,i was trying to avoid this very thing.but thnk u for ur answer.

Comment: Hi. I used your code but no changes are reflected to my buttons. Can you help?

Comment: Note that AndroidStudio creates `selectors` by default, not `shapes`.