# how to change button background color as clicked action?

Tags: android, button, click

---In android application ---

after a button clicked,its background color is changed to required. as clicked again,its color will restore original color.

How to implement it?

any response,thank you!

==================================================================================
Update: From network,i find a method to achieve this aim.
  design a drawable color in xml like this:

```
<drawable name="button_checked">#ffff0000</drawable>
```

in activity,use below code to get Drawable object:

```
Resources resource = getBaseContext().getResources();
checked_drawable = resource.getDrawable(R.drawable.button_checked);
```

in onClick function,according to a boolean variable:

```
 setBackgroundDrawable(checked_mDrawable)
```

to set button background.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Standard Android Button with a different color](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1521640/standard-android-button-with-a-different-color)

Answer (score 0):

In your js file put

$('#button').toggleClass('bg');

in your css, have your regular button css style

```
#button { background: white; }
```

and then add

```
#button.bg { background: red; }
```

So when they click on the button it will turn background red, if they click on it again, it will turn back to white.

Use whatever color / url you want for backgrounds.

Comment: thank you your response! i use java in android application,so how to implement it?

Answer (score 0):

You just need to create [a state list drawable resource](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/resources/drawable-resource.html#StateList) like below:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<selector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">

    <item android:drawable="@drawable/btn_login_pressed" android:state_pressed="true"/>
    <item android:drawable="@drawable/btn_login_normal" android:state_pressed="false"/>

</selector>
```

**Updated:**
Maybe you want the effect as RadioButton, Here is an example:

```
    <RadioButton
       android:id="@+id/tab_communication"
       android:layout_width="wrap_content"
       android:layout_height="40dp"
       android:layout_weight="1"
       android:background="@null"
       android:button="@null"
       android:drawableTop="@drawable/category_communication"
       android:paddingBottom="5dp"
       android:paddingTop="5dp" />
```

drawable/category_communication.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<selector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">

    <item android:drawable="@drawable/category_communication_checked" android:state_checked="true"/>
    <item android:drawable="@drawable/category_communication_normal" android:state_checked="false"/>

 </selector>
```

[ToggleButton](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/controls/togglebutton.html) is another choice.

Comment: i just tested your method. But what it show is not i hope. what i want is as button clicked and up,its backgound color is changed to stay color A. as i click it again,its backround color change to restore original color.

Comment: I want to know how to implement this function in general button,not RadioButton. thks!

Comment: For general button, since it has no checkable attribute, I don't know the implementation. May you can follow outcast's answer.

Comment: [ToggleButton]http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/ToggleButton.html is another choice

Comment: Thank you for your suggestion! Use ToggleButton is also good idea!

Answer (score 0):

You can do it in code dynamically(I don't know how to configure it in xml).

```
boolean flag=true;
Button button=(Button)findViewById(R.id.button);
oncreate()
{
    button.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.first_time_click);
    button.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener()
    {
    public void onClick(View v)
    {
        if (flag)
        {
            button.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.odd_time_click);        
        }else
        {
           button.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.even_time_click);
        }
        flag=!flag;
    }
    });
}
```