# Android button background color

Tags: android, button, material-design, android-button

I am trying to set the background color of a button in my app and I am unable to achieve the result that I want...

The color that I am trying to set is `holo_green_light(#ff99cc00)`. In order to do it, I am using `setColorFilter(0xff99cc00, PorterDuff.Mode.MULTIPLY);`

The color that I get is not the `holo_green_light` but a mix of lightgrey and `holo_green_light`.

I have tried using the `LightingColorFilter` without much success.

Is there a way to do it programatically, so that the button appears like a button and not a flat rectangle with the color that I need.

Comment: try using   android:background="@drawable/button"

Answer (score 92, accepted):

If you want to keep the general styling (rounded corners etc.) and just change the background color then I use the backgroundTint property

```
android:backgroundTint="@android:color/holo_green_light"
```

Comment: `android:backgroundTint` will be used only for api >= 21. use `app:backgroundTint` instead

Comment: @repitch will `app:backgroundTint` worked for every api?

Comment: Between Proctor and Repitch that should be the most common answer to this question

Answer (score 50):

This is my way to do custom Button with a different color:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<shape xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <stroke android:width="3dp"
        android:color="#80FFFFFF" />
 
    <corners android:radius="25dp" />
 
    <gradient android:angle="270"
            android:centerColor="#90150517"
            android:endColor="#90150517"
            android:startColor="#90150517" />
</shape>
```

This way you set as background:

```
<Button android:id="@+id/button"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Button"
        android:layout_marginBottom="25dp"
        android:layout_centerInParent="true"
        android:background="@drawable/button" />
```

Comment: For noob's like me, it would be helpful if you get be more explicit about where the first code sample should go.  Is it a file named Button.xml in the drawables folder?

Comment: hai Geoff. please make a drawable folder in the res folder and make one button.xml. please copy paste this code. call this xml in ur Button background. It will work.

Answer (score 18):

If you don't mind hardcoding it you can do this ~> android:background="#eeeeee" and drop any hex color # you wish.

Looks like this....

```
<Button
    android:id="@+id/button1"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
    android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
    android:layout_below="@+id/textView1"
    android:text="@string/ClickMe"
    android:background="#fff"/>
```

Comment: You lose the rounded corners and default selection states by just changing the background color though.

Answer (score 18):

Just use a `MaterialButton` and the  **`app:backgroundTint`** attribute:

```
<MaterialButton
  app:backgroundTint="@color/my_color_selector"
```

[image]

Answer (score 16):

Create  `/res/drawable/button.xml` with the following content :

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<shape xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:shape="rectangle" android:padding="10dp">
<!-- you can use any color you want I used here gray color-->
 <solid android:color="#90EE90"/> 
    <corners
     android:bottomRightRadius="3dp"
     android:bottomLeftRadius="3dp"
  android:topLeftRadius="3dp"
  android:topRightRadius="3dp"/>
</shape>
```

And then you can use the following :

```
<Button
    android:id="@+id/button_save_prefs"
    android:text="@string/save"
    android:background="@drawable/button"/>
```

Comment: I had to make the corner radius 13dp to make it visible; thanks!

Answer (score 6):

Why not just use `setBackgroundColor(getResources().getColor(R.color.holo_light_green))`?

Edit: If you want to have something which looks more like an Android button you are going to want to create a gradient and set it as the background.  For an example of this, you can check out [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1521640/standard-android-button-with-a-different-color).

Comment: Wouldn't that make the button look like a flat rectangle?

Comment: It looks like default Android buttons have a gradient as their background, so if you want to imitate that effect you're probably going to need to create a gradient yourself and set it as a background.  I added an edit to that effect.

Answer (score 5):

No need to be that hardcore.
Try this :

```
YourButtonObject.setBackground(0xff99cc00);
```

Answer (score 5):

Try this

```
<androidx.appcompat.widget.AppCompatButton
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="34dp"
    android:text="Check Out"
    android:textAllCaps="true"
    android:background="#54c2bc"
    android:textColor="#FFFFFF"
    android:textSize="9sp"/>
```

Answer (score 1):

In order to keep the style, use:

```
int color = Color.parseColor("#99cc00");
button.getBackground().mutate().setColorFilter(new PorterDuffColorFilter(color, PorterDuff.Mode.SRC));
```

Comment: why did you add mutate?

Answer (score 1):

### try this

app:backgroundTint="@color/colorGreen"

Answer (score 0):

In addition to Mark Proctor's answer:

If you want to keep the default styling, but have a conditional coloring on the button, just set the `backgroundTint` property like so:

```
android:backgroundTint="@drawable/styles_mybutton"
```

Create the associated file /res/drawable/styles_mybutton.xml, then use the following template and change the colors as per your tastes:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<selector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <!-- Disabled state-->
    <item android:state_enabled="false"
        android:color="@android:color/white">
    </item>
    <!-- Default state-->
    <item
        android:color="#cfc">
    </item>
</selector>
```

Answer (score 0):

With version [1.2.0-alpha06](https://github.com/material-components/material-components-android/releases/tag/1.2.0-alpha06) of [material design library](https://github.com/material-components/material-components-android), now we can use `android:background="..."` on `MaterialButton` components:

```
<com.google.android.material.button.MaterialButton
    android:background="#fff"
    ...
/>
```

Comment: You can use `android:background` for a drawable. If you want just to change the color, use the  `app:backgroundTint ` attribute.

Comment: To be able to use the background (e.g. using a drawable) with MaterialButton you need also to set app:background tint to null 

    app:backgroundTint="@null"
    android:background="@drawable/bg_drawable"

Answer (score 0):

I've faced the same problem with Android Studio Flamingo default setup.
But found out that you need to change the Theme to AppCompat.NoAction or so, so that the color can be visible by your designer view. There is also a theme selector option on the top of the Designer view in android studio to select theme options.

After that you should be able to see the changes in button style.
You can use your custom drawables as `android:background="@drawble/some_asset"` or using `android:backgroundTint="some_hex_color"`.

Hope that solves the problem.

Answer (score 0):

Programmatically way:

```
val pressedColor = ColorDrawable(Color.LTGRAY)
val states = arrayOf(
    intArrayOf(android.R.attr.state_pressed),
    intArrayOf(android.R.attr.state_focused),
    intArrayOf()
)
val drawables = arrayOf(
    pressedColor,
    pressedColor,
    ColorDrawable(Color.TRANSPARENT)
)
val stateListDrawable = StateListDrawable()

for (i in states.indices) {
    stateListDrawable.addState(states[i], drawables[i])
}

button.background = stateListDrawable
```