# Android button background is taking the primary color

Tags: android, xml, button, android-button, material-components-android

I've this issue, I don't know where it come from, I've created this buttons with custom background, but the background color talking the primary color and cannot change it unless change the primary color.

```
<Button
    android:id="@+id/btn_teacher"
    style="@style/normalText"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_marginBottom="@dimen/_16sdp"
    android:background="@drawable/btn_rounded_stroke"
    android:text="@string/txt_teacher" />

    <resources>
        <color name="colorPrimary">#008577</color>
        <color name="colorPrimaryDark">#00574B</color>
        <color name="colorAccent">#D81B60</color>
        <color name="bg_color">#FFD7A4</color>        
    </resources>
```

I have many buttons with different colors, so i can't change the primary color

here is my drawable background

```
 <layer-list xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" >
    <item >
        <shape android:shape="rectangle"  >
            <size android:height="@dimen/_48sdp" />
            <corners android:radius="@dimen/_24sdp" />
            <stroke android:width="@dimen/_1sdp" android:color="#59CECE" />
            <solid android:color="@android:color/white"/>
        </shape>
    </item>

</layer-list>
```

I'm using new material design by google

```
implementation "com.google.android.material:material:1.3.0-alpha02"
```

How can i override this color?
[image: this the image for buttons]

Comment: Post `@drwable/btn_round_stroke` xml

Answer (score 41):

Since you are using a **`Theme.MaterialComponents.*`** your `Button` is replaced [at runtime](https://github.com/material-components/material-components-android/blob/1.3.0/lib/java/com/google/android/material/theme/MaterialComponentsViewInflater.java) by a `MaterialButton`.

Currently the **`backgroundTint`** is still the **default** `MaterialButton` style.
It means that if you are using a custom `android:background`, you have to make sure to null out `backgroundTint` to avoid that the custom background doesn't get tinted with the `attr/colorPrimary` defined in your theme.

You have to add **`app:backgroundTint="@null"`**:

```
  <Button
    app:backgroundTint="@null"
    android:background="@drawable/.."
```

---

In any case you don't need a custom background (`btn_rounded_stroke`) in your case. You are just using a custom background only to define rounded corners. This feature is provided by default by the `MaterialButton`, then just use the **`cornerRadius`** attribute.

Use the standard `MaterialButton`:

```
    <com.google.android.material.button.MaterialButton
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="48dp"
        style="@style/Widget.MaterialComponents.Button.OutlinedButton"
        app:strokeColor="#59CECE"
        app:cornerRadius="24dp"
```

[image]

Comment: tried it not working, it turns it to blue not my custom background

Comment: @Fath.Saif post also style="@style/normalText"

Comment: really thank you so much from the bottom of my heart....❤

Comment: Thank you so much!! The parent style `Theme.MaterialComponents.NoActionBar` was the culprit!

Answer (score 5):

When Material theme is used then Button view is mapped to MaterialButtton.
There is one more way to setup the button background in this case.

```
    <style name="AppTheme" parent="Theme.MaterialComponents.DayNight.DarkActionBar"
...
        <item name="materialButtonStyle">@style/ColoredButton</item>
    </style>

    <style name="ColoredButton" parent="Widget.MaterialComponents.Button.TextButton">
        <item name="backgroundTint">@color/customButtonColor</item>
    </style>
```

Answer (score 2):

What worked for me

First create `btn_style` in your `styles.xml` or `themes.xml`

```
<style name="btn_style" parent="Widget.MaterialComponents.Button">
    <item name="backgroundTint">@null</item>
</style>
```

then in you layout apply the style and use the `color` or `drawable` that you want

```
        <Button
            android:id="@+id/btn"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:textStyle="bold"
            android:background="@color/Red"
            style="@style/btn_style"
            android:text="Button"/>
```

Answer (score 0):

In your Gradle just replace this line

```
implementation "com.google.android.material:material:1.3.0-alpha02"
```

with this

```
 implementation 'com.google.android.material:material:1.2.1'
```

Answer (score 0):

All you need to do is simply go to your themes.xml file and change the style name to:

```
style name="Theme.AnimatedLogin" 
parent="Theme.AppCompat.Light.NoActionBar"
```

in Light theme mode and to:

```
style name="Theme.AnimatedLogin"
parent="Theme.AppCompat.DayNight.NoActionBar"
```

in Dark theme mode in your theme.xml(night) file and then you can customize your button and change its colour.

Answer (score -1):

Try this .

Your Button:

```
<Button
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:textColor="#FFFFFF"
    android:layout_margin="5dp"
    android:background="@drawable/round_btn"
    android:padding="20dp"
    android:text="My Text" />
```

Here is your **round_btn** drawable:

```
<shape xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:shape="rectangle">
    <solid android:color="#008577" />
    <corners android:radius="20dp" />
</shape>
```

Comment: here is my drawable class but nothing change:
----------------------------------------------------------------------------
<layer-list xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" >
    <item >
        <shape android:shape="rectangle"  >
            <size android:height="@dimen/_48sdp" />
            <corners android:radius="@dimen/_24sdp" />
            <stroke android:width="@dimen/_1sdp" android:color="#59CECE" />
            <solid android:color="@android:color/white"/>
        </shape>
    </item>

</layer-list>