# Button border color is primaryColor of themes.xml instead of stroke color of drawable.xml

Tags: android, xml, android-layout

I created a drawable with specefic stroke color, but when I apply it to a button, the border color is the colorPrimary of themes.xml. I can't change colorPrimary because is the color I use in the top bar. If I don't call the theme in manifest.xml for the layout where I have the button, it does show the color defined in the drawable.xml

drawable:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<selector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <item>
        <shape android:shape="rectangle">
            <!-- background -->
            <solid android:color="@color/transparent" />
            <!-- border -->
            <stroke android:width="2dp" android:color="@color/green" />
            <!-- corner roundness -->
            <corners android:radius="20dp" />
        </shape>
    </item>
</selector>
```

style:

```
<style name="greenButton">
    <item name="android:background">@drawable/transparent_bg_bordered_button</item>
    <item name="android:textColor">@color/green</item>
</style>
```

Button:

```
<Button
        android:id="@+id/signInButton"
        style="@style/greenButton"
        android:layout_width="97dp"
        android:layout_height="41dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="32dp"
        android:text="Acceder"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/passwordEditText" />
```

[image: Button appearance]

Comment: What happens if you add `app:backgroundTint="@null"` to your `<Button>` tag?

Comment: It would be helpful to see your app theme's `<style>` definition, and to know what version of appcompat/material libraries you're using.

Comment: @BenP. I added `app:backgroundTint="@null"`and now it works correctly! Thanks!
The style definition of themes.xml is `<style name="Theme.FichajesDeportivos" parent="Theme.MaterialComponents.DayNight.DarkActionBar">`

Comment: Check https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63328270/android-button-background-is-taking-the-primary-color/63331089#63331089