# Background Gradient not working on Button and MaterialButton

Tags: android, xml, material-ui

> I have applied gradient along with round on Button

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<shape xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:shape="rectangle">
    <gradient
        android:angle="0"
        android:centerColor="#F82634"
        android:endColor="#FA3B6F"
        android:startColor="#FA7D6F" />

    <padding
        android:bottom="7dp"
        android:left="7dp"
        android:right="7dp"
        android:top="7dp" />

    <corners android:radius="8dp" />
</shape>


By applying `android:background="@drawable/gradient_button"`
```

**Padding** and **Corners** are shown in **xml** whereas gradient start and end color not applied.
I have also tried `backgroundTint = "@null"` but still same issue. I have replace Button with **MaterialButton** same issue occur

But when I use **AppCompatButton** it works perfectly.

> Can someone guide me what am i missing

```
<Button
        android:id="@+id/applyNowBtn"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:background="@drawable/gradient_button"
        android:text="Apply Now"
         />
```

Comment: The issue is other because I tried the same and it works fine for me.

Comment: I have the parent theme set as parent="Theme.MaterialComponents.DayNight.DarkActionBar". If i change it to AppCompat theme the buttons work fine but Material Components get messed up

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are two ways to accomplish

Change you **Button** or **MaterialButton** to **AppCompatButton**
or Use [these theme](https://stackoverflow.com/a/67466323/4134215) instead

Have a look at [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/q/31858374/4134215)

Material Component theme is still under development .Read [this article](https://medium.com/over-engineering/setting-up-a-material-components-theme-for-android-fbf7774da739)