# What's the difference between Android's "Theme.MaterialComponents.DayNight.DarkActionBar" and "Theme.MaterialComponents.DayNight.DarkActionBar.Bridge"

Tags: android, xml

I'm working on the material design of my new android app and I can't figure out what the difference between "Theme.MaterialComponents.DayNight.DarkActionBar" and "Theme.MaterialComponents.DayNight.DarkActionBar.Bridge"

When I use .Bridge, the background colors correspond with the item value I defined in "background".  Why do the colors change when I do this?

Here is my code for reference:

```
<style name="Theme.GrainGuardians" parent="Theme.MaterialComponents.DayNight.DarkActionBar.Bridge">
        <!-- Primary brand color. -->
        <item name="colorPrimary">@color/green_asparagus_night</item>
        <item name="colorPrimaryVariant">@color/green_palm_night</item>
        <item name="colorOnPrimary">@color/white</item>
        <!-- Secondary brand color. -->
        <item name="colorSecondary">@color/gold_american_night</item>
        <item name="colorSecondaryVariant">@color/gold_sunray_night</item>
        <item name="colorOnSecondary">@color/black</item>
        <!-- Status bar color. -->
        <item name="android:statusBarColor">?attr/colorPrimaryVariant</item>
        <!-- Customize your theme here. -->
        <item name="background">@color/background_night</item>
</style>
```

I've tried using both and I just see some of the colors change.  I can't find any documentation online.  Any help would be great.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [android:background not work on button with theme Theme.MaterialComponents.DayNight.DarkActionBar](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67466134/androidbackground-not-work-on-button-with-theme-theme-materialcomponents-daynig)

Answer (score 0):

Try using:

```
<item name="android:background">@color/background_night</item>
```

or

```
<item name="android:colorBackground">@color/background_night</item>
```

You shouldn't need to use a bridge theme for a new app, they were intended to make migration from AppCompat themes easier.

You should also consider using Material 3, which will become the default sooner or later. You can use the [Theme Builder](https://m3.material.io/theme-builder), which will generate everything you need to get started.