# Cannot customize button when using Theme.MaterialComponents.DayNight.NoActionBar as theme

Tags: android, android-layout, material-design, android-xml, material-components-android

I want to customize a button using my custom drawable file as follows:

**custom_button.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<shape xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:shape="rectangle">
    <solid android:color="#48cae4" />
    <corners android:radius="10dp" />
</shape>
```

But after changing the background of the button(as follows) there is no effect

```
android:background="@drawable/custom_button"
```

But if I change `<style name="Theme.A" parent="Theme.MaterialComponents.DayNight.NoActionBar">` to `<style name="Theme.A" parent="Theme.AppCompat.DayNight.NoActionBar">`, then custom drawble takes effect on the button, but then the Material Components I used, convert to normal widgets.

Comment: Check: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63328270/android-button-background-is-taking-the-primary-color/63331089#63331089

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You cannot use custom drawable for MaterialButton or using Material Theme. You can only set solid color states and set them with `app:backgroundTint` attribute. [Ref](https://material.io/components/buttons/android#using-buttons)

Create tint.xml inside `res/color/` directory:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<selector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <item android:color="?attr/colorPrimary" android:state_pressed="true"/>
    <item android:color="@color/colorSecondary" />
    ...
</selector>
```

Use it in your button or button style:

```
app:backgroundTint="@color/tint"
```