# Button on android app somehow takes a color from title, dunno how to change a title color or button color

Tags: java, android, xml, android-button

[button color takes a title color](https://i.stack.imgur.com/zX8Am.png)

Troubles with button colors, it always take a title color and idk why, I don't even know how to change a color of title

```xml
        <Button android:background="@color/white"
                android:id="@+id/showGraphButton"
                android:foreground="@drawable/changing_show_graph_button_color"
                android:foregroundGravity="right"
                android:clickable="true"
                android:enabled="false"
                android:gravity="left"
                android:text="Рассчитать корректуру "
                android:textColor="@color/darkgrey_spbsut"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="40dp"
                android:backgroundTint="@color/white">

        </Button>
    </LinearLayout>

</LinearLayout>
```

Comment: Check https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63328270/android-button-background-is-taking-the-primary-color/63331089#63331089

Answer (score 0):

Try to delete `android:background="@color/white"`. That thing reset your color of the background to the default value and if you didn't set the value of the color in the resources of the color (in the folder resources -> values-> colors.xml) it will not work