# Android default button color

Tags: java, android, xml, android-button, material-components-android

When I open a new android studio project, the default color for button is purple. I want the default color to be the gray default button color(I assume you know what I mean). I tried to change the color via xml and java and nothing worked. I want that the default button color will be gray without I'd have to change it every time.
[image]

[image]

themse.xml:

```
<resources xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools">
<!-- Base application theme. -->
<style name="Theme.HangmanGame" parent="Theme.MaterialComponents.DayNight.DarkActionBar">
    <!-- Primary brand color. -->
    <item name="colorPrimary">@color/purple_500</item>
    <item name="colorPrimaryVariant">@color/purple_700</item>
    <item name="colorOnPrimary">@color/white</item>
    <!-- Secondary brand color. -->
    <item name="colorSecondary">@color/teal_200</item>
    <item name="colorSecondaryVariant">@color/teal_700</item>
    <item name="colorOnSecondary">@color/black</item>
    <!-- Status bar color. -->
    <item name="android:statusBarColor" tools:targetApi="l">?attr/colorPrimaryVariant</item>
    <!-- Customize your theme here. -->
</style>
```

themes.xml(night)

```
<resources xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools">
<!-- Base application theme. -->
<style name="Theme.HangmanGame" parent="Theme.MaterialComponents.DayNight.DarkActionBar">
    <!-- Primary brand color. -->
    <item name="colorPrimary">@color/purple_200</item>
    <item name="colorPrimaryVariant">@color/purple_700</item>
    <item name="colorOnPrimary">@color/black</item>
    <!-- Secondary brand color. -->
    <item name="colorSecondary">@color/teal_200</item>
    <item name="colorSecondaryVariant">@color/teal_200</item>
    <item name="colorOnSecondary">@color/black</item>
    <!-- Status bar color. -->
    <item name="android:statusBarColor" tools:targetApi="l">?attr/colorPrimaryVariant</item>
    <!-- Customize your theme here. -->
</style>
```

Comment: Are you using the material components library?

Comment: No, The button color is purple by default

Comment: Post your app theme

Comment: your colorPrimary and colorPrimaryVariant is set to purple. changing these to a grey color is not working?

Comment: What is the hex value of default button color?

Comment: @Tomer You are using a MaterialComponents theme. Check the answer below. The background color of the button is based on `<item name="colorPrimary">@color/purple_500</item>`.

Answer (score 13):

Since you are using a **`Theme.MaterialComponents.*`** theme the default background color of the `Button` (which is replaced by a `MaterialButton`) is the **`colorPrimary`** defined in your app theme.
In your case:

```
<item name="colorPrimary">@color/purple_500</item>
```

You can change this value (but this will affect all widgets).

If you want to change globally the button style in your app you can also add the `materialButtonStyle` attribute in your app theme:

```
<style name="Theme.HangmanGame" parent="Theme.MaterialComponents.DayNight.DarkActionBar">
   <item name="materialButtonStyle">@style/Widget.App.Button</item>
</style>
```

with:

```
<style name="Widget.App.Button" parent="Widget.MaterialComponents.Button">
    <item name="backgroundTint">@color/...</item>
</style>
```

If you want to change this color only in the button you can use also the `app:backgroundTint` attribute removing the `android:background` attribute:

```
<Button
    app:backgroundTint="@color/..."/>
```

If you want to use a custom background using the `android:background` attribute you have to add `app:backgroundTint="@null"` to avoid that the button is tinted.

Comment: It works material3 api 31.

Answer (score 2):

I think the easiest way is to go into three xml files: src\main\res\values\colors.xml, src\main\res\values\themes.xml, and src\main\res\values-night\themes.xml

In the colors.xml, add a color and call it "button", then set the color to what you want. For a simple list of color codes, see this answer: https://stackoverflow.com/a/7323234/5374362

The line would look something like this:

```
<color name="button">#808080</color>  //That code is the gray you want.
```

In the two themes files, change colorPrimary to "@color/button"

This will affect every button in the app.

Answer (score 0):

Either, you can change the application theme in themes.xml from:

```
<style name="Theme.DemoApp" parent="Theme.MaterialComponents.DayNight.DarkActionBar">
```

to this:

```
    <style name="Theme.DemoApp" parent="Theme.AppCompat.DayNight.DarkActionBar">
```

Then, add Button Background:

```
<Button
        android:id="@+id/button"
        android:layout_width="120dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        **android:background="@color/white"**
        android:text="Submit"/>
```