# How do i change the backgroud color of a button in kotlin

Tags: android, kotlin, android-button, material-components-android

I am new to kotlin programming and i can't resolve the problem that i am facing in android studio. I followed a course on youtube, and at one point the video teaches you how to build an actual app. I want to change the backgroud color of a button that i made but whatever i do, the button keeps having the color purple.

I tryed this 2 methods:

```
android:background="@android:color/white"
android:background="#FFFFFF"
```

Can you help me guys, i would be really thankful

the entire code is: ( please do not mind the names i chose for the colors, im romanian)

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:id="@+id/padding"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:background="@color/backgroundColor"
android:gravity="center_horizontal"
android:orientation="vertical"
android:padding="16dp"
tools:context=".MainActivity"
>

<Button
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_marginTop="15dp"
    android:background="@android:color/white"
    android:backgroundTint="@color/white"
    android:text="Selecteaza data"
    android:textColor="@color/culoarePrimara"
    android:textSize="20sp"
    android:textStyle="bold"
    />
</LinearLayout>
```

This is the color:
[image]

Comment: post more code, `Activity` and layout XML especially. where have you put this not-working `android:background` line?

Comment: Did you check colors.xml if "white" has the correct code?

Comment: Guys, i do not know what to say, thank you for all the responses, i got pretty mad, deleted the project and re-coded it, using your sugestions and it worked thanks

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Android button background color](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18070008/android-button-background-color) (specifically [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/47327294/208273)) or [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/29801031/208273) for doing it in Kotlin.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

instead of `android:background="@color/backgroundColor"`

use: `android:backgroundTint="@color/backgroundColor"`

Answer (score 0):

For button background color either use custom style or `android:backgroundTint="@color/white"` (or your preferred color)

Comment: i tried it but it doesn't change the color

Comment: Which API level are you using? If it is <21 then use `app:backgroundTint` instead

Comment: i used api 27, i belive its android 8.1

Comment: It's based on whether you're using an AppCompat theme vs. a Material Components theme, not the API level.

Answer (score 0):

You can use:

```
<Button
    app:backgroundTint="@color/..."/>
```

May be you are using a `Theme.MaterialComponents.*` theme and the default background color of the `Button` (which is replaced by a `MaterialButton`) is the `colorPrimary` defined in your app theme.