# Why method setBackgroundColor() in Android Studio doesn't work?

Tags: java, android, background-color

```
mButton.setBackgroundColor(Color.GREEN) ;
```

So, I used that method to change the color of a button when it's clicked. Button was initialized like private in MainActivity and this in onCreate():`mButton = (Button) findViewById( R.id.button_count);`
I tried to cast it to View and still doesn't work. Maybe, it can help you - when I set any color in **Attribute Pane** attribute **background**, color of a button doesn't change.

I want to know how to change background color in java code or what's wrong with my program.
Thank you

Comment: That is probably a variation on [this problem](https://stackoverflow.com/q/64722733/115145).

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Android button background color](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18070008/android-button-background-color)

Comment: can you show a log of your android studio or your code ?

Comment: This [edit](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/66185313/timeline#history_491c0994-5248-4f24-8ca4-c7fb00679bfd) to the question completely changes the question and renders the existing answers and discussion confusingly off topic.

Comment: @Jon is absolutely correct; I've rolled back the edit.

Comment: @Jon what do you know about ban in stackoverflow?)

Answer (score 0):

Try with this line:

`mButton.setBackgroundColor(getResources().getColor(R.color.Green));`

**Note :** Green color defined in color.xml

Answer (score 0):

`button.setcolorfilter(Color)` was deprecated in API 29.

`button.setBackgroundColor(color)` messes with the button style.

So here is a new way to do this using `BlendModeColorFilter()`: https://developer.android.com/reference/android/graphics/BlendModeColorFilter

See the above link for documentation.

```
fun setButtonColor(btn: Button, color: Int) {
    if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= 29)
        btn.background.colorFilter = BlendModeColorFilter(color, BlendMode.MULTIPLY)
    else
        btn.background.setColorFilter(color, PorterDuff.Mode.MULTIPLY)
}
```

According to the new APIs, color filters work fine.