# color-palette or third party plugin in order to set colors in eclipse

Tags: java, android, eclipse

### Is there easy way to manipulate colors in android ?

- In dot.net we have color palette to change the color of
  objects(button-background,text-color.. etc)
- similarly is there any color palette/or/-any-plugins in object
  browser of eclipse IDE at design time

**Note**:: I am aware of changing the color by adding color codes in styles.xml and referencing it in layout.xml

Answer (score 0):

You can do this in some cases directly,

e.g in TextView you can change the Text Color by applying this statement in

**Java code**

```
 textView1.setTextColor(Color.Red);
```

for other objects like **buttons** etc. you can not change their Color Directly like **C#**.

You have to create **different .xml** file and then you will store this .xml file inb drawable folder, in your `activity_main(where button is created in your layout file) you have to make reference` 
e.g

```
<Button
    android:background="@drawable/red_button" />
```

now the colored **button .xml** file located in

> res/drawable/red_button.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>    
<selector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <item android:state_pressed="true" android:drawable="@drawable/red_button_pressed" />
    <item android:state_focused="true" android:drawable="@drawable/red_button_focus" />
    <item android:drawable="@drawable/red_button_rest" />
</selector>
```

[Check this Link for more Details](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1521640/standard-android-button-with-a-different-color)