# Change color of button

Tags: android

How can I change the color of a button using the xml files? I tried using     `android:background="@android:color/black"` but it only works for black and white as far as I can tell. Can someone explain this to me. Why not     `android:background="@android:color/blue"`?

Comment: not all colors exist by name, you can define additional colors in colors.xml and afair use ARGB color codes directly like #ff00ff00 .  But mind that assigning a background to s button disables the default multi-state background so it wont change color on press,focus... to assign all those you have to create a multistate drawable as proposed below

Answer (score 0):

You can do this with a selector file like so:

```
<item android:state_pressed="true" >
    <shape>
        <gradient
            android:startColor="@android:color/yellow"
            android:endColor="@android:color/yellow"
            android:angle="270" />
        <stroke
            android:width="3dp"
            android:color="@android:color/grey" />
        <corners
            android:radius="3dp" />
        <padding
            android:left="10dp"
            android:top="10dp"
            android:right="10dp"
            android:bottom="10dp" />
    </shape>
</item>

<item android:state_focused="true" >
    <shape>
        <gradient
            android:endColor="@android:color/orange"
            android:startColor="@android:color/orange"
            android:angle="270" />
        <stroke
            android:width="3dp"
            android:color="@android:color/grey" />
        <corners
            android:radius="3dp" />
        <padding
            android:left="10dp"
            android:top="10dp"
            android:right="10dp"
            android:bottom="10dp" />
    </shape>
</item>

<item>        
    <shape>
        <gradient
            android:endColor="@android:color/blue"
            android:startColor="@android:color/blue"
            android:angle="270" />
        <stroke
            android:width="3dp"
            android:color="@android:color/grey" />
        <corner
            android:radius="3dp" />
        <padding
            android:left="10dp"
            android:top="10dp"
            android:right="10dp"
            android:bottom="10dp" />
    </shape>
</item>
```

Name the file custom_button.xml for example, then in the actual button:

```
background="@drawable/custom_button"
```

Referenced from :
[Standard Android Button with a different color](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1521640/standard-android-button-with-a-different-color)

Answer (score 0):

Change color of button i have 2 answers for u :-

1. you can use android:background="#0000ff" for blue and for color codes u can visit http://html-color-codes.info/
2. i would suggest rather to use xml drawables to accomplish dat you will create a onclick state drawable  and normal state drawable then you will use them in one drawable. This way you can give different color during onclick.

Thx.

Answer (score 0):

you have to define drawable attibute for the items (for some reason it is required when it comes to background definitions), so:

```
  <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<selector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <item android:state_pressed="true" android:drawable="@color/red"/> <!-- pressed -->
    <item android:state_focused="true" android:drawable="@color/blue"/> <!-- focused -->
    <item android:drawable="@color/black"/> <!-- default -->
</selector>
```

Also note that drawable attribute doesn't accept raw color values, so you have to define the colors as resources. Create colors.xml file at res/values folder:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<resources>
     <color name="black">#000</color>
     <color name="blue">#00f</color>
     <color name="red">#f00</color>
</resources>
```

You can also take a look on [this](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/resources/color-list-resource.html)

Answer (score 0):

you can create a file under `res/values/` folder, and name it `color.xml` . and then add your colors in that file like this :

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<resources>
<color name="blue" >#0000ff</color>
<color name="red" >#ff0000</color>
<color name="green">#00ff00</color>
</resources>
```

And then in your xml layout , you can specify the color you want like this :

`android:background="@color/blue"`

instead of

`android:background="@android:color/blue"`

**NOTE  :** you can see this [tutorial](http://www.android-ios-tutorials.com/29/android-button-selector-example/) as an advanced step for you to use selectors on your buttons and views.