# differentiate between textview and button when background is coloured

Tags: android, button, textview

I have one `horizontal linear layout` that has one `textview` and `button` but when I apply background colour button just resembles the text view and I can't find any differnece between both.

I want to format my button so that it should be identified differently from text view.

Image of layout where there is button and text view.

[image]

In above image `Selected Option` is textview and `Update` is button as you can see both looks alike.

Can any one help me on this, As I have no clue on how to do this.

Thanks for your time.

Comment: u mean to ask for button color ? check for background attribute

Comment: @SrinathGanesh thanks for your response.. I have already applied background colour and my problem started after that... then I can't see any difference between textview and button.. please advice

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is virtually no difference between a `Button` and a `TextView`. `Button` is extended from a `TextView` only. You can clear your doubt if you look at the source code of `Button`

```
public class Button extends TextView {
    public Button(Context context) {
        this(context, null);
    }

    public Button(Context context, AttributeSet attrs) {
        this(context, attrs, com.android.internal.R.attr.buttonStyle);
    }

    public Button(Context context, AttributeSet attrs, int defStyle) {
        super(context, attrs, defStyle);
    }

    @Override
    public void onInitializeAccessibilityEvent(AccessibilityEvent event) {
        super.onInitializeAccessibilityEvent(event);
        event.setClassName(Button.class.getName());
    }

    @Override
    public void onInitializeAccessibilityNodeInfo(AccessibilityNodeInfo info) {
        super.onInitializeAccessibilityNodeInfo(info);
        info.setClassName(Button.class.getName());
    }
}
```

EDIT:

But if you just want to change the background color of the `Button` without changing the default style, you can do something like below,

```
btnName.getBackground().setColorFilter(new LightingColorFilter(0xFFFFFFFF, 0xFFAA0000));
```

Remember to remove the  `android:background=""` or `android:src=""` from your `Button` if any in xml file.

This code only changes the background color without affecting the default style. You can change the background color with the standard HEX color codes.

reference

[Standard Android Button with a different color](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1521640/standard-android-button-with-a-different-color)

Comment: Thanks for valuable information.. but for better user experience there should be difference between `button and `textview`.. Can you advice in that context..

Comment: Thanks for your code... this I need to give it in `onCreate`?

Comment: @Siva: Yes.But remember to add it after your `Button` initialization otherwise you will get `NullPointerException`.

Comment: Thanks that has done the trick....  but a small correction before doing this in XML need to remove the `Background` attribute for button and apply this code... Thanks :)

Comment: @Siva: Edited your query in the answer. Thanks for pointing it out.

Answer (score 1):

Check out this [sample](http://letustech.wordpress.com/2012/10/15/custom-style-buttons/) it has various styles you can apply to the button.
Everything is done with only colors.

Comment: @Sundeep1501.. thanks for your helpful information but problem is solved.

Answer (score 0):

```
// Try this way,hope this will help you..

<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:gravity="center"
    android:orientation="horizontal" >

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:background="@color/button_default"> // set your background color here
        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/txtSelectedOption"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="Selected Option"/>
    </LinearLayout>

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/btnUpdate"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Update"/>

</LinearLayout>
```

Comment: Thanks @Haresh for your response but I need to apply colour to the button aswell and after applying colour I can't spot any difference between textview and button.