# Android ImageButton change background

Tags: android, background, imagebutton

Is there a way to change the background on an ImageButton without creating another button for that state?

I mean, when you add an ImageButton it gets a grey background and gets slightly darker grey when selected.

Adding: `android:background="@color/white"`, will make my background white (like i want), but noting happens when selecting the button. It would be nice with something like: 
`android:background_selected ="the color you want here"`

**I want a button that has a with background in normal state and a blue background when pressing that button.**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks a lot for everyone's time. I found a great solution to what i wanted here:
[Standard Android Button with a different color](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1521640/standard-android-button-with-a-different-color)

It only requires you to create one extra xml file.

Simplified like this:

1. Create a drawable folder inside res.
2. Create custom_button.xml inside that folder (choose selector as root element).
3. Past this code and link your layout button like this android:background="@drawables/custom_button"

   ```
   <item android:state_pressed="true" >
       <shape>
           <gradient
               android:startColor="@color/yellow1"
               android:endColor="@color/yellow"
               android:angle="270" />
           <stroke
               android:width="3dp"
               android:color="@color/black" />
           <corners
               android:radius="3dp" />
           <padding
               android:left="10dp"
               android:top="20dp"
               android:right="10dp"
               android:bottom="10dp" />
       </shape>
   </item>

   <item>        
       <shape>
           <gradient
               android:endColor="@color/white"
               android:startColor="@color/white"
               android:angle="270" />
           <padding
               android:left="10dp"
               android:top="20dp"
               android:right="10dp"
               android:bottom="10dp" />
       </shape>
   </item>
   ```

Answer (score 4):

You need to create a xml File in the drawable Folder with content like this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>

<selector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <item android:drawable="@drawable/normal_background" android:state_pressed="false"/>
    <item android:drawable="@drawable/pressed_background" android:state_pressed="true"/>
</selector>
```

Than attach this as background to your button: android:background="@drawable/filename"

Source: http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/resources/drawable-resource.html#StateList

Comment: But using this i will i have to create two buttons? First this button "@drawable/normal_background" than this button "@drawable/pressed_background"

Comment: No just one Button with @drawable/backgroundxml, where backgroundxml is the filename of your xml with the selector inside.

Comment: I tried this but i dont know what @drawable/normal_background is. My project cannot a resource named normal_background

Comment: normal_background is just a wildcard for your own graphaics. You need to replace normal_background and pressed_background with the drawables which you want to show when the button is pressed or normal.

Answer (score 0):

My first piece of advice would be to use a normal button, and then change it to a white color, which you can do through Android Studio's XML editor easily, if that is what you are using, and then have it turn on blue when clicked because that is the default nature of the apps that are created from Android Studio.

Answer (score 0):

Use `OnTouchListener` for your `ImageButton`:

```
int SELECTED_COLOR = Color.RED; //set to your color
int UNSELECTED_COLOR = Color.BLUE; //set to your color
```

---

```
OnTouchListener onTouchListener = new OnTouchListener() {
    @Override
    public boolean onTouch(View v, MotionEvent event) {
           switch(event.getAction())
           {
               case MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN :
                   v.setBackgroundColor(SELECTED_COLOR); //selected color
                   break;
               case MotionEvent.ACTION_UP :
                   v.setBackgroundColor(UNSELECTED_COLOR); //unselected color
                     break;
           }
           return true;
    }
};
```

---

```
imageButton.setBackgroundColor(UNSELECTED_COLOR);
imageButton.setOnTouchListener(onTouchListener);
```

Comment: @Blackbelt are you kidding me? It is the right way to change bg of View in Pressed and UnPressed State!

Answer (score 0):

Make two xml shapes in the folder drawable:

shape_1.xml:

```
      <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" ?>
      <shape xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" android:shape="oval">
      <solid android:color="@android:color/white" />

      </shape>
```

shape_2.xml

```
     <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" ?>
     <shape xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" android:shape="oval">
     <solid android:color="@android:color/black" />

     </shape>
```

create a selector_1.xml in drawable folder:

```
     <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
    <selector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
     <item android:drawable="@drawable/shape_1"
      android:state_pressed="true" />
     <item android:drawable="@drawable/shape_2"
      android:state_pressed="false" />
     <item android:drawable="@drawable/shape_2" />
    </selector>
```

and set the selector as src of Your button:

```
            <ImageButton
    android:id="@+id/imageButton_1"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:src="@drawable/selector_1" />
```

Answer (score -1):

Create an xml file named `imagebutton_selector` in the drawable folder like this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<selector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">

<item android:state_pressed="true" android:color="@color/blue" />
<item android:color="@color/white" />

</selector>
```

than in your layout xml where you added `ImageButton` set background like this:

```
<ImageButton
    ...
    android:background="@drawable/imagebutton_selector"
    ...
 />
```

Comment: Why did this get voted down? There is something like this that i want. However, your code doesnt work. I found this thread: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1521640/standard-android-button-with-a-different-color
Similar solution to your but much longer, trying to trim it down now.

Comment: @user3711421 i used same code and its working for me.. you just want to change the color on click of image button right!!

Comment: Hmm, you still use android:src="path to the icon" right? When i run the code you provided i get an error. And no concrete advice from the LogCat.. These buttons are inside of a fragment if that might be the reason why the app stop.

Comment: @user3711421 Still not found any solution of your problem ??

Comment: I found it but couldn't post it yesterday because my account was to new.

Comment: @user3711421 Ok now post it...It can be help someone else.