# Android: button onpress remove shadow/border

Tags: android, button, onclick

I've added a couple of simple buttons to a layout and I want to remove the blue shadow/border that apears around the button when I press it. How do I customize the button's apearance on "onpress" action?

Answer (score 0):

there is no way to do this - all "looks" of buttons states are drawables. you can replace them creating own graphics or use [Holo generator](http://android-holo-colors.com/) (deprected, prefering using `AppCompat` lib)

[HERE](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1521640/standard-android-button-with-a-different-color) you have a `Selector` example and also method for coloring button ("shadow" will stay, but will be in your color matching app style)

Answer (score 0):

```
 ImageView.setColorFilter(Color.argb(255, 93, 93, 93));
```

This is gray color, you can set according to your color of image background.

Answer (score 0):

try to set Background drawable for your button as:

```
 btn.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.yellow_button);
```

yellow_button.xml :

```
<!-- pressed -->
<item android:drawable="@drawable/button_1_selected" android:state_pressed="true"/>
<!-- focused -->
<item android:drawable="@drawable/button_1_normal" android:state_focused="true"/>
<!-- default -->
<item android:drawable="@drawable/button_1_normal"/>
```