# Change Button color when pressed

Tags: java, android, android-layout, button, android-xml

I've found other answers to this but they where 2 and 6 years old so I didn't know if that was the best option.

I'm making an app that converts a simple integer in hex, oct and binary.
The user can choose in which of the three options the integer must be converted to by three buttons located at the top of the Fragment.

[image]

The effect that I'm searching for is that if the user presses one of the three Buttons, the one that has been clicked remains of a certain color.

This is my XML code

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:orientation="vertical"
android:paddingTop="16dp"
android:paddingBottom="16dp"
android:paddingRight="16dp"
android:paddingLeft="16dp" >

<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:paddingTop="20dp">

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/hex_button"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_weight="3"
        android:text="@string/hex_button"/>

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/binary_button"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_weight="3"
        android:layout_toRightOf="@id/hex_button"
        android:text="@string/binary_button"/>

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/oct_button"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_weight="3"
        android:layout_toRightOf="@id/binary_button"
        android:text="@string/oct_button"/>

</LinearLayout>

<RelativeLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/converted_button"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_centerVertical="true"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:inputType="number"
        android:text="@string/convert_button"/>

    <android.support.design.widget.TextInputLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:paddingTop="50dp">

        <EditText
            android:id="@+id/int_edit_text"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:hint="@string/integer_edit_text_hint"
            android:inputType="number" />

    </android.support.design.widget.TextInputLayout>

    <android.support.design.widget.TextInputLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:paddingBottom="50dp"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true" >

        <EditText
            android:id="@+id/converted_number_edit_text"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:inputType="number" />

    </android.support.design.widget.TextInputLayout>

</RelativeLayout>
```

Do I have to make changes in the Java code or just in the XML to achieve this?

Answer (score 2):

You will need to change color of button widget for onClick() method

Answer (score 1):

You will have to set an onClickListener for the buttons. In this listener, you check which button invoked the event that triggered the listener, and you change the color of this button there.

So you will have to do it in the java code. A listener basically looks like this:

```
Button button = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button_id);
button.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
    public void onClick(View v) {
        // Change Button Color here, and do other stuff
        Button button = (Button) findViewById(v.getId());
        button.setBackgroundColor(int color);
    }
});
```

Comment: Yeah I've already set an OnClickListener because I needed it for other purposes, was that easy? I should have looked at the Button library before asking.

Comment: Why did you declare a Button again in the OnClick() method? Shouldn't I just do:
button.setBackgroundColor(int color) ?

Comment: You do not know which button invoked the listener, so you have to check with the ID of the event which button's color you want to change.

Comment: By the way that command gives the button a coloured, not sized, rectangular shape that is completely different from the button shape

Comment: then you will have to work with color filter. here is some explanation: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1521640/standard-android-button-with-a-different-color

Answer (score 1):

You can use two background drawables : one for active and other for inactive.

Add ClickListeners on all the buttons and toggle the backgrounds using `setBackgroundResource();` method.

Answer (score 0):

This use in xml activity like for button :-

```
<Button
    android:id="@+id/button_id"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_weight="3"
    android:layout_toRightOf="@id/binary_button"
    android:text="@string/oct_button"
    android:onClick="changeColor" 
/>
```

Now in java class use like....

```
private boolean isChangeColor=true;
public void changeColor(View v)
{
     if(isChangeColor)
     v.setBackgroundColor(Color.BLACK);
     else
     v.setBackgroundColor(Color.WHITE);//use your original color here
     isChangeColor=!isChangeColor;
}
```

Comment: That ruins the buttons shape, because as soon as you press one it becomes a black square with a completely different shape

Comment: you have to change its color OR use image like
t.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.mybuttonImage);

Comment: I want the button to remain of the same exact shape but change its color from that grey to another color

Comment: Get image and name it as mybuttonImage and place in drawable or copy then use this code you will look it awesome <3

Comment: Which image? I want to use the Google's Material Design Palette