# How to use native Android XML on Xamarin?

Tags: android, xamarin, xamarin.forms

I need a button to which I can set custom font and color. I created a custom renderer for the font, and set the `BackgroundColor` to whichever color I need, but the problem is that when I disable the button, the background color doesn't change. I found [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1726352/700998) solution but I have no idea how to use it in my Xamarin Forms app. Any suggestions?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can save the state list selector in your **Resources/drawable** directory with a name like **button_bg.xml**. Then in your layout xml file you can set your button's background like this

```
<Button
android:layout_width="wrap_content"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:background="@drawable/button_bg"/>
```

Please check this guide on using resources:https://developer.xamarin.com/guides/android/application_fundamentals/resources_in_android/part_1_-_android_resource_basics/

**EDIT:**

The above solution is for classic Xamarin Android, for Xamarin Forms you can achieve the same by setting the background to the button within the custom renderer class as described here:
http://dailydotnettips.com/2016/03/05/applying-styles-for-xamarin-forms-control-in-android-from-xml-file/

```
public class CustomButtonRenderer : ButtonRenderer
{
protected override void OnElementChanged(ElementChangedEventArgs&amp;lt;Xamarin.Forms.Button&amp;gt; e)
{
base.OnElementChanged(e);
var btn = this.Control as Android.Widget.Button;
btn?.SetBackgroundResource(Resource.Drawable.Style);
}
}
```

Another approach is to use **Xamarin Forms global styles** as described in the guide:
https://developer.xamarin.com/guides/xamarin-forms/user-interface/styles/application/

Also there is **Xamarin Dynamic Styles** which enables you to change styles in runtom: https://developer.xamarin.com/guides/xamarin-forms/user-interface/styles/dynamic/

Comment: I am using Xamarin Forms though

Comment: Can I pass values to that xml?

Comment: You can define the colors for the different states as color resources in your Resources/values file, and reference them in your state list drawable

Comment: i'm trying to make a universal button. I want to be able to set just the color from xaml and then calculate the disabled state color and then apply them all in a button renderer.

Comment: I believe Dynamic Styles can do this, though not sure as I didn't use it before

Comment: weird. there clearly is an entry `custom_button` in `Resource.Drawable`, the xml file is present in Resrouces\drawable, build aciton is set to `Android Resource` and despite that, I'm getting an error "Android.Content.Res.Resources NotFoundException..."

Comment: Well, this is another issue, is that a runtime exception? make sure you can reference the file from code through Resource.Drawable.custom_button. otherwise check if the xml file has errors

Comment: Great, glad to hear that