# Is there a way to make a disabled button clickable in Android Studio?

Tags: android, android-studio, kotlin, android-layout

In Android Studio I have a Kotlin project with a button that sends an SMS message. When the Send SMS permission for the app is denied, the button is disabled. When a user clicks the disabled button, I would like to display a toast message to the user:

```
Toast.makeText(this, R.string.smsDisabled, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show()
```

However, after much research I haven't been able to make this disabled button clickable. I have tried things like `smsButton.isClickable = true` on the button, but it still doesn't work. If it is possible to style the button to simply *look* like it is disabled, that would work too. My button style is currently set to `@style/Widget.MaterialComponents.Button` and I haven't had any success in changing the button colors. I have tried applying a background, backgroundTint, custom theme, and creating a custom background like in [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1521640/standard-android-button-with-a-different-color/1726352#1726352).

I am new to Android Studio so I have limited knowledge and experience. Is there a way to achieve this functionality?

Comment: Disabled means not clickable. Instead of disabling it, just change its style so it has a different color.

Comment: You don't necessary need to disable the button, just change the style to emulate a disabled stated. Handle the validation on the onClickListener and when you create the button the first time, on the oncreate in your activity/fragment. Also if you can't change the background color that's another problem.

Comment: @javdromero As I stated, I also don't know how to style the button. Should I refactor the question to be more focused on this?

Comment: @Tenfour04 Oh, that makes sense. As I said in the question, I am having trouble styling the button as well. Should the question be more about that?

Comment: You should probably read the documentation first, there's a lot of it that talks about styling a `MaterialButton`: https://material.io/components/buttons/android#theming-buttons

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is what you can do:

```
if (isPermissions) {
        //keep the button as it is or do what you have to when button is enabled
    } else {
        //change the button color and maybe icon two
        button.setBackgroundColor(ContextCompat.getColor(applicationContext, R.color.grey))
        button.setOnClickListner {
            //show toast
            Toast.makeText(this, R.string.smsDisabled, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show()
        }
    }
```

Answer (score -1):

`isClickable` only makes it clickable once again if the click is disabled with the same attribute.

Try:

```
button.isEnabled = true
```